# Understanding Javascript's OOP: instances modifying other instances

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I'm having some trouble understanding why modifying a property in instance `a` modifies the same property on instance `b`.

```
var A = function (){

};

A.prototype.data = {
    value : 0
};

var a = new A();
var b = new A();

console.log(a.data.value, b.data.value); // 0, 0
a.data.value = 5;
console.log(a.data.value, b.data.value); // 5, 5
```

Shouldn't the prototype keyword make the `data` variable an instance variable ?

This seems not to be the case in this example which executes as expected:

```
var B = function (){
    this.data = {
        value : 0
    };
};

var i = new B();
var j = new B();

console.log(i.data.value, j.data.value); // 0, 0
i.data.value = 5;
console.log(i.data.value, j.data.value); // 5, 0
```

I'm confused as why the prototype method wont work. Maybe i'm lacking some conceptual knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prototype in js is a data *shared* between all instances of that class, it's like a static variable from classic oop languages. Sometimes it's usefull to put some methods/fields in .prototype to save memory on runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Because it's really doing this:

```
var A = function (){

};

var someObj = { value:0 };

A.prototype.data = someObj;
```

So all instances of A now have a property named `data` which points to the object `someObj`.  Across all instances, this is the same object.  And you are changing the `value` inside that object.

`A` does not own `value`.  It holds a reference to an object that owns `value`.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the prototype keyword make the data variable an instance variable ?

It does exactly the opposite. The `A.prototype` is shared by all objects created by `A`. When you index an object created by `A`, if the index is not present, JavaScript will attempt to resolve that index via the object's prototype (e.g. `o.constructor.prototype`). In this case, you're indexing `a` and `b` with `data`, which doesn't exist in those objects, so it uses the one in their prototype.

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` have the same prototype. so their prototypes share properties. this is the difference between [classical and prototypal inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450582/classical-vs-prototypal-inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

Just the opposite. The prototype is shared among all instances. JavaScript is a prototypal language, which is more general than classic OO languages. I good summary is
[Prototypal inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html). You also might learn a little about the [io language](http://www.iolanguage.com/) which is a more "pure" prototypal language that might help to understand JavaScript better.