# Javascript Inheritance: Parent's array variable retains value

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to use inheritance in JavaScript here, and I found problem having array value in **Parent** class that is inherited by a **Child** class. Below code is normal inheritance:

```
var Parent = function() {
    this.list = [];
};

var Child = function() {};

Child.prototype = new Parent;
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

var obj1 = new Child;

obj1.list.push("hello");

console.log(obj1.list); // prints ["hello"];
```

When I initialized new **Child** object (inherits Parent which contains array variable named **list**) to **obj1** and tried to push **obj1.list** with a value "hello", **obj1.list** prints ["hello"] .. so far so good.

The problem comes when I did the above example and I tried to initialize new **Child** object to **obj2** then push **obj2**'s **list** with a value "goodbye", and **obj2.list** now prints ["hello", "goodbye"]. (See the code below:)

```
var obj2 = new Child;

obj2.list.push("goodbye");

console.log(obj2.list); // prints ["hello", "goodbye"];
```

I might have a misconception here, but the **list** array in **Parent** is somehow retaining the value and I don't know why.

This is a big trouble because if I reuse the **Parent** class to many other child classes like the case above, if **Parent** has array variable shared to its child classes, the value will be shared to the other child classes as well, which is unexpected for me.

What I expected is, the **Child** class represents new object, same goes to **Parent** class when **Child** class is initialized to **obj1**, which then when I initialize new **Child** object to **obj2**, the pushed value from **obj1** should not be shared with **obj2**.

-- Question --

Can anyone help me find out why the **list** (the array variable of **Parent**) in the example above retains the values/share the values that are initiated by the Child objects (in above case, **obj1** and **obj2**)?

If you have another solution that could solve this problem, it will be very nice of you, but I'll be happy to find out the problem above first.

Comment: Because both instances refer to the same `Parent` instance as their prototype and therefore to the same array. There have been many JavaScript OOP questions here, you should have a look at them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undesrtanding Javascript's OOP: instances modifying other instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541788/undesrtanding-javascripts-oop-instances-modifying-other-instances) and [Javascript prototype property not working as expected with array and object fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230085/javascript-prototype-property-not-working-as-expected-with-array-and-object-fiel)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When a child object has a property inherited from its prototype object, what's really happening is that the child has a *reference* to the prototype, which contains the property. The child doesn't have its own copy of it. So both children are using the same array — the one on the (one) `Parent` prototype object you've assigned to `Child.prototype`.

First some pictures, then more text. :-)

`new Parent()` gives you this:

```
+-----------------+
| Parent instance |
+-----------------+
| list = []       |
+-----------------+
```

...which you then assign to `Child.prototype`.

Then, `new Child()` gives you this:

```
+------------------+
| Child instance 1 |
+------------------+        +-----------------+
| (prototype)      |------->| Parent instance |
+------------------+        +-----------------+
                            | list = []       |
                            +-----------------+
```

Doing `new Child()` again gives you another one:

```
+------------------+      +------------------+
| Child instance 1 |      | Child instance 2 |
+------------------+      +------------------+
| (prototype)      |---+  | (prototype)      |---+
+------------------+   |  +------------------+   |
                       |                         |
                       |                         |     +-----------------+
                       +-------------------------+---->| Parent instance |
                                                       +-----------------+
                                                       | list = []       |
                                                       +-----------------+
```

So as you can see, all of the `Child` instances are *sharing* the same `Parent` instance (their prototype), which has an array on it.

When you say:

```
var obj = new Child();
obj.list.push("foo");
```

...here's what the JavaScript engine does when it sees `obj.list`:

1. Looks to see if `obj` has its *own* property called `list`. If not, then:
2. Looks to see if `obj`'s prototype has its *own* property called `list`. If not, then:
3. Looks to see if `obj`'s prototype's prototype has its *own* property called `list`.
4. Etc. until we run out of prototypes.

In your case, since `obj` doesn't have its *own* `list` property, the engine looks to its prototype (the `Parent` instance you assigned to `Child.prototype`), which in this case does have the property. So that one is used. It's not copied to the child or anything, it's *used*. And of course, since it's an array, pushing something on the array actually pushes it onto the array.

If you were to *assign* something to `obj.list`, then `obj` would get its *own* `list` property, breaking the chain. So putting `this.list = [];` in `Child` would give each child its own list.

You'll see this any time a prototype has an *object reference* on it, where the object is a type that can be modified (a "mutable" object). Arrays, Dates, plain objects (`{}`), RegExps, etc., they all have state and they can all be modified, so you'd see it with them. (`String` instances are immutable, so although this same thing happens, you don't see any effect from it because the string cannot be changed.)

With primitives, although you inherit them, you can't change their state (you can only *replace* them with a new primitive with a different state), so you don't see this same effect. So if `obj` inherits the property `foo` from its prototype, and `foo` is `42`, `alert(obj.foo)` will get the value from the prototype and show "42". The only way to change `foo` is to say `obj.foo = 67` or similar — which gives `obj` its *own* copy of `foo`, distinct from the prototype's copy. (This is true even if you use things like `++` and `--`, e.g. `++obj.foo`; that really gets evaluated as `obj.foo = obj.foo + 1`).

Comment: Your awesome ascii graphics warrant more than +1, but that's all I'm allowed to reward

Comment: Super awesome explanation. Thank Crowder, not only you define me why's list in my code example is actually a reference, but now I understand how the prototype works in your 1,2,3,4 points. :) (oh .. and nice ASCII-art)

Answer (score 3):

The thing you're missing here, is that `Parent.list` is being instantiated only once; when you copy its' prototype into `Child.prototype`.

Instantiating a "subclass" in JavaScript does *not* automatically invoke the parent constructor. Thus, all instances of `Child` will share the same instance of the array.

Modifying the constructor of `Child` to invoke the parent constructor should be the cure you seek for your ailment:

```
var Child = function() {
    Parent.call(this);
};
```

Obviously you already have some knowledge on the subject, but if you're interested, here's a few texts on the topic worth a read:

- [OOP in JS, Part 2 : Inheritance](http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html)
- [Classical Inheritance in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html)
- [Prototypal Inheritance in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html)

Comment: Thanks nikc! honestly, your sample code is the one that actually solve my latest problem this second. I forgot to use .call that leads me to this question.