# Javascript: array member variable not working as instance variable in prototypical inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I am trying to use javascript inheritance in my code. Following is the jsfiddle for the same.
http://jsfiddle.net/Fetsz/3/

```
var baseObject = Object.create(Object, {  
    // this works as an instance variable for derived objects  
    name: {
        writable: true,
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        value: null    
    },   
    // this should act as instance variable for derived objects   
    values: {
        writable: true,
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        value: []    
    },
    displayAlert: {
        value: function (){
            alert("Alert from base object");
        }
    }
});

var derivedObj1 = Object.create(baseObject, {});    
var derivedObj2 = Object.create(baseObject, {});    

function displayValues (obj) {
    alert("values for " + obj.name + "\n" + JSON.stringify(obj.values));
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    derivedObj1.name = "Object 1";
    derivedObj2.name = "Object 2";

    derivedObj1.values.push("DO1 element");
    derivedObj2.values.push("DO2 element");

    derivedObj1.displayAlert();

    // should display values added only for derivedObj1
    displayValues(derivedObj1);

    // should display values added only for derivedObj2
    displayValues(derivedObj2);
});
```

I also checked following question which nicely explains why my code doesn't work. [Javascript Inheritance: Parent's array variable retains value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311032/javascript-inheritance-parents-array-variable-retains-value)

I need to have an array member variable in every derived class which will contain certain values. I was trying to achieve the same by adding array in base class. As mentioned in above question, to achieve the same, I will have to add array member to each derived class. Is there any other way to achieve this without modifying every derived class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables can't be on the prototype if you don't want them to be shared by all instances. You could create a second object with just the property definition for the array,and pass it as the second parameter to `Object.create`:

```
var arrDef = {
        values: {
            writable: true,
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            value: []
        }
}
var derivedObj1 = Object.create(baseObject, arrDef);    
var derivedObj2 = Object.create(baseObject, arrDef);
```

Comment: Thanks. This will solve my issue. Only problem is I already have good number of derived objects along with long property list. Implementing this would mean changes at a lot of places in the code. I am trying to find out a method to achieve it with minimal changes.

Comment: @Nilesh In this case it would be very simple if you were using the "pseudo-classical" inheritance pattern; then all you'd have to do would be adding a new property from the constructor.

Comment: pseudo-classical pattern did the job for me. Though the changes were not minimal, it seemed like right way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

When they are created, both `derivedObj1.values` and `derivedObj2.values` point to the same array object. If you were to first reassign each one using `derivedObj1.values = [];`, in the same way as you are reassigning the `name` property, your code would behave as expected.

Instead of adding the `values` property to the original baseObject, you could create an `init` method that adds an array to the instance:

```
var baseObject = Object.create(Object, {  
    // this works as an instance variable for derived objects  
    name: {
        writable: true,
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        value: null    
    },   
    // this should act as instance variable for derived objects   
    init: {
        writable: true,
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        value: function(){
            this.values = [];
        }
    },
    displayAlert: {
        value: function (){
            alert("Alert from base object");
        }
    }
});

var derivedObj1 = Object.create(baseObject, {});
derivedObj1.init();
var derivedObj2 = Object.create(baseObject, {});
derivedObj2.init();
```

Comment: Thanks Asad. In my code, property lists supplied while creating derived objects already contain init method. Still I think changes will be minimal if I try to add a method in baseObject and have it called for every object. I am going to give it a try and test now.