# Why doesn't "var derived1 = new Object(base)" set the derived1.prototype to base?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance, object-create

Given the following code sample:

```
var base = {
    one: "one",
    two: 2,
    test: function() { return "test"; }
};

var derived1 = new Object(base);

function Ctor() { };
Ctor.prototype = base;
var derived2 = new Ctor();

var proto1 = Object.getPrototypeOf(derived1);
var proto2 = Object.getPrototypeOf(derived2);

var isProto1Base = proto1 === base;
var isProto2Base = proto2 === base;
```

I had expected both isProto1Base and isProto2Base to be true.  However, isProto1Base === false and isProto2Base === true.  Why is that?

EDIT: Fixed title to reflect code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Object(base)` is not the same as `Object.create(base)`.

`new Object(x)` will box `x` into an object.

In particular, `new Object(base) === base` is true.

For more detail, see the [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.2.1):

> 1. If value is supplied, then
>
>    1. If Type(value) is Object, then
>
>       1. If the value is a native ECMAScript object, do not create a new object but simply return value.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that behavior was very unexpected to me. I'm tempted to never use "new" as it doesn't really do what it's generally meant to do in other languages and can be misleading.

Comment: @JamesCadd: It depends where you're using `new`.  There is nothing wrong with using `new` for your own constructor functions.

Comment: Thanks, I see that now. New makes fine sense when used with your own constructor functions but otherwise likely doesn't do what I intent. Have read a good bit of the Annotated ES5 link you posted and it's quite helpful.

Comment: @JamesCadd - You might want to look at JavaScript's powerful prototypal inheritance capabilities. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450582/classical-vs-prototypal-inheritance/18023164#18023164

Comment: @JamesCadd: See also http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/