# Javascript: Prototype representation of lightweight data holder

Tags: javascript

I was reading about Object Oriented JS, and trying to understand whether prototype based inheritance is best in my case. I just read Eric Elliot post on the superiority of this method over classical pattern [here](http://ericleads.com/2013/02/fluent-javascript-three-different-kinds-of-prototypal-oo/)

In my case, I have to model, say 10,000 instances of a `type or class` called `Shape` . I need each object hold on to its state, say `size`. Would using clone to extend the prototype (2nd method in Eric's post) causes the methods to clone too?? From his example,

```
var proto = {
  hello: function hello() {
    return 'Hello, my name is ' + this.name;
  }
};

var george = _.extend({}, proto, {name: 'George'});
```

does in the above case, creating 10,000 instance would clone hello into all the instances?

If that is the case, what is the best approach for me. My `type/class` holds 10 primitive values, and more act as a holder of data than abstracting behavior. Requirements,

1. Each instance hold on to private data.
2. Have some common methods to get/set those data (or just properties)
3. Easy to convert to Json

Comment: okay to use Backbone lib?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use backbone. I do use jQuery, but wonder more to do it in pure javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var george = _.extend({}, proto, {name: 'George'});
```

In above code, you are using [underscore's extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) (you need underscore lib) method. If you create object like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
 var obj = _.extend({}, proto, {name: 'George'});
}
```

all 1000 objects will be like this.

```
{
  {name: 'George'},
  hello: function hello() {
    return 'Hello, my name is ' + this.name;
  }
};
```

But below two methods share same hello function among all 1000 objects. So pick any one of this as per your wish.

**classical approach.**

```
var proto = function (name) {this.name = name || ""};

proto.prototype.hello = function hello() {
    return 'Hello, my name is ' + this.name;   }

var p2 = new proto({name: "george"});

p2.hello() //"Hello, my name is george"
```

**using Object.create()**

```
var proto = {
  hello: function hello() {
    return 'Hello, my name is ' + this.name;
  }
};

var p = Object.create(proto, {name: {value: "george"}})

p.hello() //"Hello, my name is george"
```

You should have clear understanding before start using [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). It is only supported on modern browsers. Below links can help you to understand this more

[link 1](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/object.create-the-new-way-to-create-objects-in-javascript.html), [link 2](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/javascript-object-creation.html), [link 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff925952%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Comment: THis is one SO answer by Eric http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450582/classical-vs-prototypal-inheritance about the same. Anyway, above look simpler.